# Vimeo video embed can't play in Firefox Mac OS

Tags: macos, firefox, vimeo

Do you meet this problem before? When I opened the video in Firefox,it played well but not with video embed. The video has play button but when I clicked on the button, nothing happen. I try to disable all add-ons, open in private mode, modify the config of Firefox just like [this article](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/923633) but it doesn't work.

I am using Firefox version 22.0 on Mac.
The link for vimeo video here:
http://vimeo.com/19761686